# ScrollView not scrolling all components properly

Tags: react-native

I have cards written like this, they scroll horizontal but the last card, whenever I scroll it's not shown, below, is the image of the current code.

They are price cards that scroll horizontally, kindly help me fix this. I have banged my head around it and it seems I have failed

Please help me guys am in need of real help

[image]

```js
class Pricing extends React.Component {
  state = {
   ...
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        horizontal={true}
        scrollEnabled
        pagingEnabled
        scrollEnabled
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        snapToAlignment="center"
      >
        {this.state.FlatListItems.map(item => (
          <View style={styles.subContainer} key={item.id}>
            <View style={{
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}>
              <View>
                <Image
                  source={item.image}
                /></View>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.subType}>{item.subType}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textSub}>{item.textSub}</Text>
              </View>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.currency}>{item.amount}<Text style={styles.currencyText}> Month</Text></Text>
              </View>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Subscribe</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  subContainer: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.22,
    shadowRadius: 10,
    elevation: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 15,
    marginTop: 20,
    width: '50%'
  },
})

Pricing.navigationOptions = {
  header: null
}

export default withNavigation(Pricing);
```